# Can't find my db file

Tags: android

My app creates sqlite database which file path starts with "/data/data/". From what I can see, data is stored correctly. But when I try to find the file itself (with ES Explorer), I just can't! Even the path "/data/data/" doesn't exist. Where can it be?

Answer (score 2):

You can find your database in

> /data/data/your.application.package/databases/your_db_name

This is the default path to your database

Answer (score 1):

You don't have permission to look at that folder in your file explorer. In an emulator the same happens in the Eclipse file explorer. You can however access this path in the debug mode.

It really is in `/data/data/your.application.package/databases/dbname.db`

Comment: How can I use File explorer in "debug mode" on my phone?

Answer (score 0):

```
/data/data/[your_package_name]/databases/[your_db_name].db
```